# C# Better way of managing UI graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, resources, compact-framework, embedded-resource

I'm building a UI framework for a mobile application and I have a question about managing UI graphics.

Right now I'm storing all the graphics as embedded resources.  But the GUI part of the project is seperated into 3 different Projects and NameSpaces, each containing graphics as embedded resources.  One of the Projects is a base type and doesn't know about the other two, and the other two Projects need resources from their NameSpace and Assembly and from the third (base) Namespace and Assembly

What I have been doing is when a resource is requested via the file name, I go through each of the three project's Assembly object's list of GetManifestResourceNames, sort them, then search for the first string that contains the file name.  I'm noticing that for each graphic it is taking 11-14 ms just to get this string!  When all is said and done, I'm looking at 60-100 ms just in resource name lookup

I know there must be a better way to dynamically find a resource across projects and namespaces using only the file name.  Any help with this would be excellent!

Also, having the resources be embedded isn't a constraint.  If there is a better solution that doesn't involve ER, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60-100ms isn't bad as a one-off operation, so you could create your own cache class which gets this out of the way early on during app execution - it could use a `Dictionary` object so you get very fast lookup times from that point on.

If you don't have the list in advance, you could fall back on a 'lazy-loaded' cache, i.e. the value is looked up the first time it's requested, then stored for future accesses.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  So, how would you recommend setting up the Dictionary?  The key being the image name and the assembly is the value?  IDK how big Assembly objects are, if they are small (just pointers to static objects) that would be fine, but if they are huge, I only have 32 mb to work with since it's .netCF...

Comment: You're trying to get or cache objects based on a filename?  `Dictionary<string,object>` would do it: then just look in the dictionary and you'll have your object in microseconds :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What I was asking was should I set the Dictionary up like `Dictionary<string,Assembly>` and if the Assembly object was just a pointer or if it was a very large object.  This is because I am very limited in the size of the Heap.  That's why I'm not caching the actual Image objects.

Comment: Yes, unless it's a `struct` it will just be a reference that's stored in the dictionary.  I see what you're getting at, if there are that many images using `Assembly` seems to be the way to go.